# ROS_INFO_ONCE in Python

Tags: ros, rospy, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an equivalent to `ROS_INFO_ONCES` in rospy?

I found `rospy.loginfo_throttle()` but nothing like `rospy.loginfo_once()`. Is this really not implemented or just hidden somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258341/ros_info_once-in-python/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2017-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-03-31**:
Not quite sure, but I think that they do not exist in python. They are implemented in C++ using macros which are not that easy to translate in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In python, there is no log once, but since Lunar we can use. Please refer http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging

---

Originally posted by [haryngod](https://answers.ros.org/users/25155/haryngod/) with karma: 30 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-04-11**:
To have the actual code here: Since Lunar, there is `rospy.loginfo_once`.